# @ModelAttribute formed model cannot be used in another Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations, modelattribute

My UserController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/userRegistration")
public class UserController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute(user);
        return "userForm";
    }

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onFormSubmit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {   // **#1**
    return "redirect:userSuccess.htm";                // **#2**
    }

}
```

My SuccessController.java

```
@Controller
public class SuccessController {

    @RequestMapping("/userSuccess.htm")
    public String getSuccessPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){       // **#3**
        return "userSuccess";
    }
}
```

I am not getting `"user"` model in `SuccessController` and so when I use `${user.name}` in `userSuccess.jsp`, I don't get any value.

When I set user model at Line 1, why don't I get this value in another controller? If I keep this model in Session using `@SessionAttributes`, I can access it in another controller.

Then what is the scope of models formed using `@ModelAttribute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the request, unless modified with a `@SessionAttributes` as [described here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib). (Delta the other cases [described here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args).) You're doing a redirect--request attributes are lost; it's a new request.

You answered your own question in your text: when you keep it in session, it's available across controllers and redirects, because it's in the session. If you don't keep it in session, it's not.